# Cloud Computing - Blue Cloud computing and comparison of clouds

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, force.com

Can anyone explain the Architecture of Blue Cloud Computing and Its features. 
And any place to find comparison of cloud computing technologies like Amazon , Google , Azure , force.com.

thank you all

Comment: "Blue Cloud" looks like just an old IBM branding for their cloud initiative.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 3 types of cloud computing:

- Infrastructure as a Service: Where you get access to (virtual) machines very quickly, but you install and setyp those machines. Amazon EC2 is a good example of this. http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/
- Software as a Service: Where you use some Software the is hosted by the supplier. Sales force.com and SharePoint online are good examples of this.
- Platform as a Service: Where you get a platform of which you can run your applications. This is what Azure is.

Blue Cloud is (was?) infrastructure as a services based on VMWare instances http://www.fool.com/investing/general/2009/06/17/what-became-of-ibms-blue-cloud.aspx

All the search results for blue cloud seem very old.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud computing is a model for enabling ubiquitous, convenient, on-demand network access to a shared pool of configurable computing resources (e.g., networks, servers, storage, applications and services) that can be rapidly provisioned)

Blue Cloud is the ibm cloud which is paas services. It supports several programming languages and services as well as integrated DevOps to build, run, deploy and manage applications on the cloud

Comparison between aws,google,azure and salesforce 
https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-best-compare-Salesforce-Azure-Amazon-Web-Services-or-other-cloud-platforms-for-building-an-enterprise-level-software-company

Answer (score 0):

There are four main types of [cloud computing](https://stldigital.tech/blog/choose-the-best-cloud-model-platform-that-can-accelerate-your-business/): private clouds, public clouds, hybrid clouds, and multiclouds.
There are also three main types of cloud computing services:
Infrastructure-as-a-Service (IaaS)
Platforms-as-a-Service (PaaS)
Software-as-a-Service (SaaS)

The primary objective of the "Blue Cloud" project is to facilitate distributed computing within data centers, rather than performing tasks on individual machines or through remote servers.